# Commutator of operators in relativistic quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, commutator, causality, bells-inequality

I am an undergrad student currently reading [Bell Nonlocality review paper by Brunner et al. (2014)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2849). There is a part of the paper that I found weird. On page 425, on the set of quantum behaviours (see equation (14) if you use the arxiv link above), they say:

> We call the corresponding set $\mathcal{Q'}$ if $$p(ab|xy) = \left< \psi \right| M_{a|x} M_{b|y} \left| \psi \right>$$ where $\left| \psi \right>$ is a state in a Hilbert space $H$ defining proper measurements and satisfying $[M_{a|x}, M_{b|y}] = 0$.

In relativistic quantum field theory, shouldn't the condition $$[M_{a|x}, M_{b|y}] = 0, \quad \forall M_{a|x} \, \forall M_{b|y}$$ only for spacelike separated events? For timelike separated measurements, it is not obligatory to have $[M_{a|x}, M_{b|y}] = 0$.

Comment: The two properties $a$ and $b$ may be such that their operators commute even when the points are not spacelike separated.

Comment: But the paper didn't specify $a$ and $b$. According to my knowledge, in general, the commutator inside the light-cone is allowed to be nonzero. My question about the paper is the statement $[M_{a|x}, M_{b|y}] = 0$, which is in general not true inside the light-cone.